# Can anyone suggest me a package in Python for running panel data?

Tags: python, statistics

I am particularly looking for dynamic panel data models estimated using GMM or another method with bias correction. It seems that statsmodels has some panel data specifications, but I was not able to discover which of them are available.

Comment: There must be packages for calling R from Python ...